# Too many connections error with Laravel 5.4 and Mariadb

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I have recently upgraded my laravel app from 5.1 to 5.4. My server is now on PHP 7 and Maria db 10.1.22. Now I am getting a really weird error. Sometimes, I would just try to refresh my browser and PHPMyAdmin would display `#1040 - Too many connections`. Other times I would click on a new link on my app and then would get this same error. I did some research on the internet and executed the command below:

```
show variables like 'max_connections`
```

The above command gave 100. Which I then increase to 500.

But now I still get the error. This is weird to me because I have oracle mysql 5.6 installed on another server and max_connections is 151 and for over a year and a half I have not experienced this error.

When I run the command `show processlist`, I get the result below and this keeps increasing. is this normal?

[image]

What could be the issue with Mariadb and how can I fix it.

Comment: Weird! Is this being logged in laravel log file? Can you check the stack trace?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am not sure if you guys found the solution or not but I was facing the same problem as well and found the solution. As we upgraded our laravel application from 5.2 - 5.4, we missed something important. php artisan queue:work has been upgraded as well.

In laravel 5.2, when we execute queue:work. It just process one job at a time but in laravel 5.4 queue:work creates a connection for your queue and keeps it connected. So if you have queue:work in your cron to run every minute it will create a new connection every minute and that is why we get the error of too many connections.

I did not find this information on laravel 5.4 documentation. I was going through php artisan to see the description of queue:work and found out that the description is changed.

This is description in laravel 5.2:

> queue:work >>>> Process the next job on a queue

This is description in laravel 5.4

> queue:work >>>> Start processing jobs on the queue as a daemon

As you can see the difference in what they are meant to do.

I hope that this helps you out.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I found the answer months ago. Just forgot to post the answer.

Comment: Hi, so what is the solution ? not executing queue:work in the cron every minute but juste once to start the daemon ? thx

Comment: How can i set cron job for queue in laravel 7. Please help, I'm also getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a silly observation, but did you use `DB::disconnect('foo')` to closes the conenctions of your db?

Anyway, the db closes automatically, so the problem may be somewhere else, did you try monitoring?

A very powerful tool to monitor MySQL is `innotop`. You can find it here:

https://github.com/innotop/innotop

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2453899/edit)

Answer (score 0):

What *webserver* are you using.  If Apache, then what is the setting of [*MaxRequestWorkers*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html) (formerly called `MaxClients`) for it?  Generally it should be no more than about 20.

If that is set to more than `max_connections`, that would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: Hi @Rick James I am using Apache. I can't find MaxClient in httpd.conf file. Please where is it located

Comment: Hi @Rick James. I have checked. `MaxRequestWorkers: 150` and `max_connections: 151`

Comment: That's tighter than I would like.  I'm surprised that 500 did not make the problem go away.  Perhaps I am looking the wrong direction.  Is there only one Apache server?  Is something doing "connection pooling"?

Comment: There is just one Apache server. I have a cron entry that is running every minute to execute my schedule commands. When I execute `show processlist`, I see my db listed multiple times and column "Command" has value Sleep repeatedly.

Comment: 150 from Apache + 1 from cron + 1 from you watching > 151.

Comment: Hi @Rick James. I have brought down MaxRequestWorkers to 20 as suggested but I still get thesame error. What can we be missing?

Comment: Or maybe laravel 5.4 is opening a connection for each query and not closing them or reusing existing connection

Comment: I have a question @Rick James. If MaxRequestWorkers=20 and max_connections=151, what would Apache do if the number of connections become 151?

Comment: Apache would not create more than 20 and would be oblivious to the 151.  It it got to 151, the other connections would be coming from somewhere else -- perhaps this is the problem?  Or...

Comment: If you are thinking that more than 20 users might ask for web pages simultaneously?  Then Apache would queue them up and let them get one of the 20 slots as they come available.  Apache is better at this than MySQL is; MySQL simple spits at the client, saying "too many connections, go away".

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your input @Rick James. I am not gonna rest until I solve this issue. I have attached an image to the question. Is it normal?

Comment: It is "normal" to have some connections "Sleeping".  Connection pooling leads to extra pseudo-connections living on.  On the other hand, that _may_ be an unusual number of connections that did something 2 seconds.